# How to avoid whitespace when two variables are combined in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want two variables to be combined like ${type1}${type2} but spaces can be added between these types.

```
type Unit = '%' | 'px' | 'em' | 'vh' | 'vh' | 'rem' | 'ex'

type CssSizeType = `${number}${Unit}`

let marginSize : CssSizeType = '10      px' // not error
```

How do I prevent whitespace? and why doesn't it throw an error in this case?

Comment: This is a known issue and is being tracked in [TypeScript issue 46109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46109).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `bigint` type instead, which is likely more appropriate in this case.

```
type Unit = '%' | 'px' | 'em' | 'vh' | 'vh' | 'rem' | 'ex'
type CssSizeType = `${bigint}${Unit}`

let marginSize: CssSizeType = '10      px' // error
let marginSize2: CssSizeType = '10.5px' // error
```

If you want decimals, you could use:

```
type Unit = '%' | 'px' | 'em' | 'vh' | 'vh' | 'rem' | 'ex'
type CssSizeType = `${bigint}${Unit}` | `${bigint}.${bigint}${Unit}`

let marginSize: CssSizeType = '10      px' // error
let marginSize2: CssSizeType = '10.5px' // ok
```